# PostgreSQL query timeout do not stop JDBC client attempt to read data from the server

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem in my multithreaded application that uses JDBC PostgreSQL driver. Sometimes it hangs for many hours with various queries to various databases. To stop such hangs I set query timeout to 10 minutes, but from my application it doesn't work, it not return after this time.

jstack of such hung thread looks like:

```
"srv_thead_160621090411" #1560 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0d24001800 nid=0x150f runnable [0x00007f0c83ffd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:70)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:283)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1799)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    - locked <0x00000005dc2f9f88> (a org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
```

From server side I see that query (pid 31657) is running for > 30 seconds, but then server detects client disconnection. I think that after 10 minutes server receive "CANCEL query with PID 32657" command from JDBC driver, but this connection ended after disconnection:

```
2016-06-21 07:05:23.340 CEST [31657]: [1-1] postgres [unknown] 192.168.1.124(58729) dbtest %LOG:  duration: 30689.838 ms  execute <unnamed>: SELECT MAX(do_nr) + 1 AS numer FROM dokumenty WHERE (do_typ  =  'WZ' or upper(do_typ)  =  upper('WZ_tmp')) AND do_dataw BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 00:00:00' AND do_magazyn = 29
2016-06-21 07:05:23.340 CEST [31657]: [2-1] postgres [unknown] 192.168.1.124(58729) dbtest %LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2016-06-21 07:05:23.340 CEST [31657]: [3-1] postgres [unknown] 192.168.1.124(58729) dbtest %LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2016-06-21 07:09:24.107 CEST [21]: [8151-1]     %LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2016-06-21 07:14:52.620 CEST [31703]: [1-1] [unknown] [unknown] 192.168.1.124(58860) [unknown] %LOG:  PID 31657 in cancel request did not match any process
```

I think that this cancel comes from JDBC driver but I'm not sure. Strangest to me is that after 10 minutes JDBC client still wants to read data from server. It hang for a few hours until I restarted the whole service.

I think there are 2 problems:

1. Something is wrong with network connections: server detects disconnection but client thinks it is still connected.
2. Query timeout do not stop JDBC attempt to read data from the server.

Is there something I can do to stop my hung thread that wants to read data from the server?

My environment:

client:

Java: 1.8.0_92 (Oracle Corporation)

PostgreSQL Native Driver PostgreSQL 9.4.1208

server:

PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

Comment: Just in case: do you have a standalone reproducer for the issue?

Comment: No. It happens randomly, with various databases and various queries.

Comment: Michael, I've filed a pgjdbc issue for your case: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/750